# Set locale on windows process

Tags: .net, locale, cultureinfo

I want to start a .NET application on Windows 10 that uses my system's Locale / CultureInfo. Instead of having to change my systems settings, could I add a parameter to the start command so that the Locale is set for that process?
I've looked everywhere, but not found the answer yet.

Comment: You should be able to check/set your current culture while starting your application with System.Globalization.CultureInfo currentCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;

Comment: I can only run the code, not change it.